# MySQL service wont start on XAMPP

Tags: mysql, xampp

I installed MySQL Server 5.6, but soon after I had to install XAMPP.

When I try to start MySQL it just hangs at...

```
Attempting to start MySQL app...
```

The errors in the logs are as follows...

```
140401 15:05:43 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
140401 15:05:43 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
140401 15:05:43 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
140401 15:05:43 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
140401 15:05:43 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
140401 15:05:43 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: Error: space header page consists of zero bytes in data file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1
140401 15:05:43 InnoDB: Could not open or create data files.
140401 15:05:43 InnoDB: If you tried to add new data files, and it failed here,
140401 15:05:43 InnoDB: you should now edit innodb_data_file_path in my.cnf back
140401 15:05:43 InnoDB: to what it was, and remove the new ibdata files InnoDB created
140401 15:05:43 InnoDB: in this failed attempt. InnoDB only wrote those files full of
140401 15:05:43 InnoDB: zeros, but did not yet use them in any way. But be careful: do not
140401 15:05:43 InnoDB: remove old data files which contain your precious data!
140401 15:05:43 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
140401 15:05:43 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
140401 15:05:43 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
140401 15:05:43 [ERROR] Aborting

140401 15:05:43 [Note] c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete
```

I tried stopping the MySQL56 service in services, but still it didnt work

I also tried changing ports in my.ini to 3307, but still no luck

I have obviously restarted everything after these changes but it just stays hanging on the attempt to start

Comment: You installed Mysql alone...and then you install XAMPP over it??

Comment: It seems to me like simple permissions issue. Try to reinstall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstall both and reinstall XAMPP with MySQL included. Many times these installs will run as administrators and then you won't have rights to modify them if it sees you as a different user.

You could also try right clicking on the icon to start XAMPP and choose "Run as Administrator" before uninstall / reinstall and see if that solves it.

Comment: Thank you , interesting, when I run as admin I get a new error - MySQL shut down unexpectedly. This may be due to a blocked port...etc"

Comment: Just checking, is this a work computer or home? Just curious if there are security policies in place beyond standard. If you can, check which ports are supposed to be open and do so. That "could" happen automatically during installation of XAMPP, but it probably doesn't.

Comment: its a computer in a college actually, I dont think there'd be security issues as I was using MySQL fine before this.

Anyway, i followed your instructions and it has worked, however when I click admin, It tells me... "Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at localhost."

Comment: now it seems to be working after messing around with ports in the configurations, Im getting an access denied for phpmyadmin, but thats probably beyond this particular question, thank you